# After Git clone from GitHub, I do not see my branch

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on GitHub. It contains `master` and one branch.

When I clone it, I obtain only `master` and do not see my branch.

Why is it so? How can I see all branches in the repository?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

By default, `git clone` creates only one branch: the currently checked out one, generally master. However, it does create remote tracking branches for all other branches in the remote. Think of these as local copies of the remote's branches, which can be updated by fetching. They're not real local branches, as they're intended only as pointers to where the remote's branches are, not for you to work on.

If you run `git branch -a` you'll see all branches, local and remote. If you want to see just the remote ones, use `git branch -r`. If you prefer a visual history display, try `gitk --all` (or `gitk --remotes`).

To create a local branch to work on, use

```
git branch <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>
```

That'll create a new local branch using the remote's branch as the starting point.

Comment: a shorter syntax that's supported is git branch -t origin/<branch-name>

Comment: @adymitruk: Not sure when -t was introduced, but it's not in Git 1.6.3.1 and earlier.  If -t isn't there, people can use --track instead.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk 

using the command `git branch -t origin/<branch-name>` is tracking the local `master`

Comment: As an answer below suggests, it needs to be `git branch -t branch-name origin/branch-name`

Answer (score 28):

You can directly do:

```
git checkout <original-remote-branch-name>
```

This automatically creates a local branch which tracks the remote branch with the same name.
Do this always after cloning, if you want to work on a particular branch other than master.

**Note:** When you clone the remote name is by default 'origin' which is different from the remote name used in other machines where you are developing. So, you can initially name your remote before cloning or push to origin ever after.

Comment: Is this possible in atom without relying on the cli? Is there a gui here?

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
git branch -r
```

This will show you all remote branches. You can then do:

```
git branch -t my_local_branch origin/remote_branch
git checkout my_local_branch
```

Then do your work and then push to the remote branch.