# Git branch not shows any branch when I create a branch

Tags: git, github

I did a `git clone` of a project, after that, I have creater a branch:

```
git checkout -b myBranch
```

And after this line it shows: Switched to a new branch `myBranch`

But, when I type this:

```
git branch
```

It doesn't show anything... I just want to clone a branch of my project, I tried this: [After git clone, I do not see my branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999541/after-git-clone-i-do-not-see-my-branch) but I get nothing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the output from `git branch`? Doesn't it even show `master`?

Comment: It doesn´t show anything.

Comment: And what does `git status` state?

Comment: It works ! I going to look for what happened. =) Thanks.